# Validating form wizard using jQuery Form Validator plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to get the "jQuery Form Validator" plugin (http://formvalidator.net/) to play nicely with my form wizard. What I need is for each step of the wizard to be validated upon clicking a "Next" button and to now allow the user to the next step or to submit the form without the validation check passing.

My code:

```
<form>
<div class="form-wizard">
<input fields>
</div>

<div class="form-wizard">
<input fields>
</div>

<div class="form-button-bar">
<button class="btn btn-default btn-small form-wizard-previous" id="previous"><i class="icon-circle-arrow-left"></i> Previous</button>&nbsp;
<button class="btn btn-success btn-small form-wizard-next" id="nextbutton"><i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i> Next</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-small form-wizard-submit form-submit-ajax" id="formSubmitAjax"><i class="icon-external-link"></i> Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

The fields are validated if I interact with them (so the validation is working), but I am still able to press the "Next" button to continue to the next step.

The code used to validate the fields is simply:

```
<script>
$.validate();
</script>
```

Please let me know if you require further explanation or additional code.

Comment: Show your code.  You said validation is working but you've shown no jQuery code at all.  Also, are you talking about this one?:  http://jqueryvalidation.org

Comment: Sorry I am talking about this one: http://formvalidator.net/
The function called to validate a form is simply: $.validate();

Comment: Please edit your OP with a link to the plugin so it's clear what we're all talking about.  `.validate()` is also the same for other validation plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bad example, but here it is.

```
function doValidate() {
        $("form").submit(function() {
            var validationResult = validateSomething();
            if (!validationResult)
            {
              return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate the forms out, or add an ignore field to the steps not taken yet.
I'm guessing next isn't a "submit" so it's not being disabled.

you could also add a class to each section and look for those with error, if they are all valid, enable the button

Comment: The plugin adds the class "error" to each input field which fails validation. I am unsure of how to check the fields for that class and then enable/disable the "Next" button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the wizard forms into separate forms.
For example,

```
<div class="form-wizard">
   <form id="frm1" name="frm1">
      <input fields>
   </form>
</div>
<div class="form-wizard">
   <form id="frm2" name="frm2">
      <input fields>
   </form>
</div>
```

Action code for Next button:

```
$("#nextbutton").click(function(){
   // $currentStep to keep track which form to validate
   // use .validateForm() function in "jQuery Form Validator" plugin 
   // accept arguments language and config

   if ($currentStep == 1){
      $result = $('#frm1').validateForm();
   }
   else if ($currentStep ==2){
      $result = $('#frm2').validateForm();
   }

   if (!$result){
      //Stop Navigate to Next Step
   }
});
```